# graalvm native-image. failed with exit status 30

Tags: graalvm, graalvm-native-image

graalvm use native-image to build a simple helloworld class
os: windows 11
code :

```
    Main.java
    public static void main(String args[]){
        System.out.println("hello world");
    }
```

java version: graalvm 21
path :  graalvm 's dir
java_home: %JAVA_HOME%

result:
failed with exit status 30.
how can i fixed it .

```
D:\workspace-java\graalvm-test>native-image Main  --verbose
-imagemp \
'C:\Program Files\Java\graalvm-jdk-21.0.2+13.1\lib\svm\graal-microservices.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\graalvm-jdk-21.0.2+13.1\lib\svm\library-support.jar' \
'-H:CLibraryPath=C:\Program Files\Java\graalvm-jdk-21.0.2+13.1\lib\svm\clibraries\windows-amd64' \
'-H:Path@driver=D:\workspace-java\graalvm-test' \
'-H:Class@explicit main-class=Main' \
'-H:Name@main-class lower case as image name=main' \
-H:ImageBuildID@driver=da41c134-b116-8d85-75f5-28007c9968bb \
'-H:Features@jar:file:///C:/Program%20Files/Java/graalvm-jdk-21.0.2+13.1/lib/svm/library-support.jar!/META-INF/native-image/com.oracle.svm/thirdparty/native-image.properties+api=com.oracle.svm.thirdparty.gson.GsonFeature' \
'-H:Features@jar:file:///C:/Program%20Files/Java/graalvm-jdk-21.0.2+13.1/lib/svm/library-support.jar!/META-INF/native-image/com.oracle.svm/polyglot/native-image.properties+api=com.oracle.svm.polyglot.groovy.GroovyIndyInterfaceFeature,com.oracle.svm.polyglot.scala.ScalaFeature'
]
Error: Image build request for 'main' (pid: 53908, path: D:\workspace-java\graalvm-test) failed with exit status 30
com.oracle.svm.driver.NativeImage$NativeImageError:** Image build request for 'main' (pid: 53908, path: D:\workspace-java\graalvm-test) failed with exit status 30**
        at org.graalvm.nativeimage.driver/com.oracle.svm.driver.NativeImage.showError(NativeImage.java:2337)
        at org.graalvm.nativeimage.driver/com.oracle.svm.driver.NativeImage.build(NativeImage.java:1927)
        at org.graalvm.nativeimage.driver/com.oracle.svm.driver.NativeImage.performBuild(NativeImage.java:1873)
        at org.graalvm.nativeimage.driver/com.oracle.svm.driver.NativeImage.main(NativeImage.java:1847)
        at java.base@21.0.2/java.lang.invoke.LambdaForm$DMH/sa346b79c.invokeStaticInit(LambdaForm$DMH)
```

use  --verbose to show detail log
installed the c++ library
set the JAVA_HOME and path
fllow the graalvm official install documentation